# Value error for format while using data_format option

Tags: robotframework

I am new and I am trying to get our required `date_format`. I Tried to check other formats in `date_format` also. But i am getting this error.

> ***ValueError: time data '2018-11-16 11:18:58' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'***

This is generated by the following script:

**Robot Test Suite**

```
    *** Settings ***
    Library  DateTime

    *** Variables ***
    ${UTC_OFFSET}  - 5 hours
    ${LOCAL_TIME_ZONE}  -05:00
    ${LOCAL_DATE_FORMAT}  %m/%d/%Y

    *** Test Cases ***
    Test title
        ${Supplied_Date}=  DateTime.Get Current Date  time_zone=UTC  increment=${UTC_OFFSET}  result_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
        Log  ${Supplied_Date}  console=true
        ${Supplied_Date}  DateTime.convert date  ${Supplied_Date}    result_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S   exclude_millis=${True}   date_format=${LOCAL_DATE_FORMAT} %I:%M:%S %p
        Log  ${Supplied_Date}  console=true
```

Comment: The error seems pretty clear - the date you're getting doesn't match the format you're expecting. Notice that the date you're getting has dashes in it, but the format you're expecting has slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple mix-up of the `result_format` and `date_format` values:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  DateTime

*** Variables ***
${UTC_OFFSET}  - 5 hours
${LOCAL_TIME_ZONE}  -05:00
${LOCAL_DATE_FORMAT}  %m/%d/%Y

*** Test Cases ***
Test title
    ${Supplied_Date}=  Get Current Date  
    ...    time_zone=UTC  
    ...    increment=${UTC_OFFSET}  
    ...    result_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
    Log  ${Supplied_Date}  console=true

    ${Supplied_Date}  Convert Date  
    ...    ${Supplied_Date}    
    ...    date_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S   
    ...    exclude_millis=${True}   
    ...    result_format=${LOCAL_DATE_FORMAT} %I:%M:%S %p
    Log  ${Supplied_Date}  console=true
```